# ubuntu 12.04 cannot login

Tags: login

I am using Ubuntu 12.04. I cannot login. I get to the grub menu and go root, delete my `/home/user/.Xauthority` file and change my password. I move `/home/user/.profile` to `/home/user/profile`, reboot, and I can login (this is fixed by moving .profile to some other name).

But if I am idle and Ubuntu displays the screensaver, I cannot login. I have pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> and removed `/home/user/.Xauthority`. I check the existence of `/home/user/.profile` and it does not exist. There is no way for me to login to X from the keyboard connected to the box. I can `ssh -CXY` to the ubuntu box and login without any problem. Can someone help me fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

how about creating your new /home/user/.profile:

```
# ~/.profile: executed by the command interpreter for login shells.
# This file is not read by bash(1), if ~/.bash_profile or ~/.bash_login
# exists.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files for examples.
# the files are located in the bash-doc package.

# the default umask is set in /etc/profile; for setting the umask
# for ssh logins, install and configure the libpam-umask package.
#umask 022

# if running bash
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
    # include .bashrc if it exists
    if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
    . "$HOME/.bashrc"
    fi
fi

# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
fi
```

copy, paste, save ..