# Command line mode only -- successful login only brings me back to login screen

Tags: login

whenever I log in the screen goes black, I see a glimpse of terminal-esque text, and then it brings me back to the log in screen (Ubuntu 12.04).  I can enter and log in via the command line.  The guest account works find.  I think this happened because I edited some Xorg related file trying to make an external monitor work with my laptop.  I copy pasted from a forum post so I dont recall the file or what i put in the file.  Can't find the forum post again and my bash history wasn't recorded from that session.

I tried reinstalling Xorg and ubuntu-desktop, nvidia, resetting any configs I could find... I'm really at a loss of what to do.  Here's my /.xsession-errors:

```
/usr/sbin/lightdm-session: 11: /home/seth/.profile: -s: not found
Backend     : gconf
Integration : true
Profile     : unity
Adding plugins
Initializing core options...done
Initializing composite options...done
Initializing opengl options...done
Initializing decor options...done
Initializing vpswitch options...done
Initializing snap options...done
Initializing mousepoll options...done
Initializing resize options...done
Initializing place options...done
Initializing move options...done
Initializing wall options...done
Initializing grid options...done
I/O warning : failed to load external entity "/home/seth/.compiz/session/108fa6ea48f8a973b9133850948930576700000017740033"
Initializing session options...done
Initializing gnomecompat options...done
** Message: applet now removed from the notification area
Initializing animation options...done
Initializing fade options...done
Initializing unitymtgrabhandles options...done
Initializing workarounds options...done
Initializing scale options...done
compiz (expo) - Warn: failed to bind image to texture
Initializing expo options...done
Initializing ezoom options...done
** Message: using fallback from indicator to GtkStatusIcon

(compiz:1846): GConf-CRITICAL **: gconf_client_add_dir: assertion `gconf_valid_key (dirname, NULL)' failed
Initializing unityshell options...done
Nautilus-Share-Message: Called "net usershare info" but it failed: 'net usershare' returned error 255: net usershare: cannot open usershare directory /var/lib/samba/usershares. Error No such file or directory
Please ask your system administrator to enable user sharing.

Setting Update "main_menu_key"
Setting Update "run_key"
Setting Update "launcher_hide_mode"
Setting Update "edge_responsiveness"
Setting Update "launcher_capture_mouse"
** Message: moving back from GtkStatusIcon to indicator
compiz (decor) - Warn: failed to bind pixmap to texture

** (zeitgeist-datahub:2128): WARNING **: zeitgeist-datahub.vala:227: Unable to get name "org.gnome.zeitgeist.datahub" on the bus!
failed to create drawable
compiz (core) - Warn: glXCreatePixmap failed
compiz (core) - Warn: Couldn't bind background pixmap 0x1e00001 to texture
compiz (decor) - Warn: failed to bind pixmap to texture
** Message: No keyring secrets found for Sonic.net_356/802-11-wireless-security; asking user.
compiz (decor) - Warn: failed to bind pixmap to texture
compiz (decor) - Warn: failed to bind pixmap to texture
** Message: No keyring secrets found for Sonic.net_356/802-11-wireless-security; asking user.
** Message: No keyring secrets found for Sonic.net_356/802-11-wireless-security; asking user.
** Message: No keyring secrets found for Sonic.net_356/802-11-wireless-security; asking user.
** Message: No keyring secrets found for Sonic.net_356/802-11-wireless-security; asking user.
** Message: No keyring secrets found for Sonic.net_356/802-11-wireless-security; asking user.
** Message: No keyring secrets found for Sonic.net_356/802-11-wireless-security; asking user.
** Message: No keyring secrets found for Sonic.net_356/802-11-wireless-security; asking user.
** Message: No keyring secrets found for Sonic.net_356/802-11-wireless-security; asking user.
** Message: No keyring secrets found for Sonic.net_356/802-11-wireless-security; asking user.
** Message: No keyring secrets found for Sonic.net_356/802-11-wireless-security; asking user.
** Message: No keyring secrets found for Sonic.net_356/802-11-wireless-security; asking user.
** Message: No keyring secrets found for Sonic.net_356/802-11-wireless-security; asking user.
[2348:2352:12678840568:ERROR:gpu_watchdog_thread.cc(231)] The GPU process hung. Terminating after 10000 ms.
[2256:2283:14450711755:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_nss.cc(1542)] handshake with server mail.google.com:443 failed; NSS error code -5938, net_error -107
[2256:2283:14450726175:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_nss.cc(1542)] handshake with server mail.google.com:443 failed; NSS error code -5938, net_error -107
[2256:2283:14450746028:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_nss.cc(1542)] handshake with server mail.google.com:443 failed; NSS error code -5938, net_error -107
[2256:2283:14464521342:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_nss.cc(1542)] handshake with server mail.google.com:443 failed; NSS error code -5938, net_error -107
[2256:2283:14464541249:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_nss.cc(1542)] handshake with server mail.google.com:443 failed; NSS error code -5938, net_error -107
[2256:2283:14690775186:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_nss.cc(1542)] handshake with server mail.google.com:443 failed; NSS error code -5938, net_error -107
[2256:2283:14690795231:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_nss.cc(1542)] handshake with server mail.google.com:443 failed; NSS error code -5938, net_error -107
[2256:2283:14704543843:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_nss.cc(1542)] handshake with server mail.google.com:443 failed; NSS error code -5938, net_error -107
[2256:2283:14704566717:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_nss.cc(1542)] handshake with server mail.google.com:443 failed; NSS error code -5938, net_error -107
[2256:2283:14766138587:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_nss.cc(1542)] handshake with server mail.google.com:443 failed; NSS error code -5938, net_error -107
[2256:2283:14857232694:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_nss.cc(1542)] handshake with server mail.google.com:443 failed; NSS error code -5938, net_error -107
[2256:2283:14930901403:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_nss.cc(1542)] handshake with server mail.google.com:443 failed; NSS error code -5938, net_error -107
[2256:2283:14930965542:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_nss.cc(1542)] handshake with server mail.google.com:443 failed; NSS error code -5938, net_error -107
[2256:2283:14944566814:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_nss.cc(1542)] handshake with server mail.google.com:443 failed; NSS error code -5938, net_error -107
[2256:2283:14944592215:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_nss.cc(1542)] handshake with server mail.google.com:443 failed; NSS error code -5938, net_error -107
[2256:2283:15170929788:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_nss.cc(1542)] handshake with server mail.google.com:443 failed; NSS error code -5938, net_error -107
[2256:2283:15170947382:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_nss.cc(1542)] handshake with server mail.google.com:443 failed; NSS error code -5938, net_error -107
[2256:2283:15184585015:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_nss.cc(1542)] handshake with server mail.google.com:443 failed; NSS error code -5938, net_error -107
[2256:2283:15184605475:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_nss.cc(1542)] handshake with server mail.google.com:443 failed; NSS error code -5938, net_error -107
[2256:2283:15366189036:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_nss.cc(1542)] handshake with server mail.google.com:443 failed; NSS error code -5938, net_error -107
[2256:2283:15410983381:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_nss.cc(1542)] handshake with server mail.google.com:443 failed; NSS error code -5938, net_error -107
[2256:2283:15411569689:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_nss.cc(1542)] handshake with server mail.google.com:443 failed; NSS error code -5938, net_error -107
[2256:2283:15431632431:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_nss.cc(1542)] handshake with server mail.google.com:443 failed; NSS error code -5938, net_error -107
[2256:2283:15431674438:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_nss.cc(1542)] handshake with server mail.google.com:443 failed; NSS error code -5938, net_error -107
[2256:2283:15457304356:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_nss.cc(1542)] handshake with server mail.google.com:443 failed; NSS error code -5938, net_error -107
[2256:2283:15656020938:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_nss.cc(1542)] handshake with server mail.google.com:443 failed; NSS error code -5938, net_error -107
[2256:2283:15656042383:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_nss.cc(1542)] handshake with server mail.google.com:443 failed; NSS error code -5938, net_error -107
[2256:2283:15674651268:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_nss.cc(1542)] handshake with server mail.google.com:443 failed; NSS error code -5938, net_error -107
[2256:2283:15674671786:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_nss.cc(1542)] handshake with server mail.google.com:443 failed; NSS error code -5938, net_error -107
[2256:2283:16052544301:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_nss.cc(1542)] handshake with server mail.google.com:443 failed; NSS error code -5938, net_error -107
[2256:2283:16057387653:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_nss.cc(1542)] handshake with server mail.google.com:443 failed; NSS error code -5938, net_error -107
[2256:2283:16157122849:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_nss.cc(1542)] handshake with server mail.google.com:443 failed; NSS error code -5938, net_error -107
[2256:2283:16157123851:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_nss.cc(1542)] handshake with server mail.google.com:443 failed; NSS error code -5938, net_error -107
[2256:2283:16157125473:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_nss.cc(1542)] handshake with server mail.google.com:443 failed; NSS error code -5938, net_error -107
[2256:2283:16157126544:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_nss.cc(1542)] handshake with server mail.google.com:443 failed; NSS error code -5938, net_error -107
[2256:2283:16157129682:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_nss.cc(1542)] handshake with server mail.google.com:443 failed; NSS error code -5938, net_error -107
```

If anyone can help me out, I'd be forever grateful

Answer (score 2):

I ran into a very similar issue, running Ubuntu 12.04. Not sure what I did to cause it, but I would login to my account and it would just immediately kick me back to the login screen. I could also login to the Guest account, but not my account. Finally, I had the same compiz errors in my .xsession-errors file.

After reading this post: [ubuntu 12.04 cannot login](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140612/ubuntu-12-04-cannot-login) I decided to try renaming the .Xauthority, the .Xauthority-c and .Xauthority-l files so that X wouldn't recognize them. After that I was able to login. Checked my home directory and a new .Xauthority file was generated. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you so much, remove those files allowed me to connect! (For the lazies `sudo rm .Xauthority*`.)